# Can't manage to load GeoJSON from PostGIS to Leaflet

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql, leaflet, geojson

I am trying to load GeoJSON from Postgres database to Leaflet app with a PHP script. I tried a couple of different approaches but can't get to the solution.

First of all, this is my **PHP script:**

```
<?php 
$db = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=webmap101;', 'postgres', '123456');
$sql = $db->query("SELECT id, name, category, ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(geom,4326))::json as geom FROM cdmx_attractions ORDER BY name");
$features=[];
while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $feature = array(
    'type'=>'Feature');
    $feature['geometry'] = json_decode($row['geom']);
    unset($row['geom']);
    $feature['properties'] = $row;
    array_push($features, $feature);
}
$featureCollection = ['type'=>'FeatureCollection', 'features'=>$features];
echo json_encode($featureCollection);
?>
```

which seem to return a **valid GeoJSON** (tested with https://geojsonlint.com/):

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-99.186538764,19.419330699]},"properties":{"id":3,"name":"Chapultepec Park","category":"Park"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-99.169386527,19.360599286]},"properties":{"id":4,"name":"Coyoacan","category":"Neighborhood"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-99.311104535,19.312817199]},"properties":{"id":7,"name":"Desierto de los leones","category":"Park"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-99.18632235,19.426167975]},"properties":{"id":2,"name":"Museum of Anthropology","category":"Museum"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-99.141254116,19.435377742]},"properties":{"id":6,"name":"Palaciode Bella Arts","category":"Place"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-99.101052134,19.288539899]},"properties":{"id":5,"name":"Xochimilco","category":"Place"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-99.133409191,19.432698836]},"properties":{"id":1,"name":"Zocalo","category":"Place"}}]}
```

So far, I tried to load data on a map with **`JSON.parse()`**

```
    var lyrAttractions;
    $.ajax({
        url: "load_attractions.php", 
        success: function(response) {
            lyrAttractions = L.geoJSON(JSON.parse(response));
            lyrAttractions.addTo(map)
    }});
```

which returns this error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse ()

Most online resources are suggesting different way of loading GeoJSON to leaflet, which looks something like this:

```
        var lyrAttractions;
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: "load_attractions.php", 
            success: function(response) {
                lyrAttractions = L.geoJSON(response);
                lyrAttractions.addTo(map);
        }});
```

In this case, I don't get an error, but points are simply not plotted on the map.

I am following one of the online courses on creating mapping applications and I've seen quite a lot of other people stuck at this point. Also, my PHP knowledge is close to none, so if there is a problem in my PHP script I would really appreciate if explained in a bit more detail.

Thanks

Comment: Call after loading the data `map.fitBounds(lyrAttractions.getBounds())`, then the map is centered to the markers

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I'm afraid nothing really happens, since points/markers are not plotted on the map in the first place. Also, all points should appear in my default zoom extent anyway.

Comment: log the response and the lyrAttractions with `console.log(lyrAttractions)` and `console.log(lyrAttractions.getLayers()` does they have data?

Comment: They don't. ```console.log(lyrAttractions)``` returns undefined and consequently ```console.log(lyrAttractions.getLayers()``` returns Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLayers' of undefined

Comment: @FalkeDesign Just one more thing. If I `console.log(response)` just before `JSON.parse()` line, the code logs a whole php script, which might cause _Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse ()_ error. Not sure if that helps at all.

Comment: It sounds like your PHP code isn't running at all. Do check your webserver configuration.

Comment: @IvanSanchez You were right, the problem was with webserver. Since I am working with VS Code, I was opening index.html with Live Server extension which by itself does not support PHP. I've set up Apache webserver and everything seems to be working just fine. Thanks!